# Spearman's Correlation using Stata

Tags: correlation, stata, biostatistics, spearman-rho

I am trying to use Stata for the first time to calculate Spearman's Rank Correlation for differences in weight and hemoglobin between annual visits for a small dataset. Do I enter the differences with the negative sign directly or do I square the differences first?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your research question. If you want to test whether hemoglobin and weight tend to increase or decrease together, then do not change the sign.

However, if you hypothesize that a greater change in weight is associated with a greater change in hemoglobin, **regardless** of increase or decrease, then you may take the absolute value. From a biomedical stand point this second hypothesis can appear a bit sloppy. However there could be an underlying factor modifying the association (e.g. for males, the greater weight they lost, the greater their hemoglobin increased; for female, the greater weight they lost, the greater their hemoglobin decreased.) So, this test may not be completely worthless. It just needs more justification.

If non-parametric test is chosen, squaring or taking absolute value does not change the result. But this is not true for parametric. In your scenario, taking absolute values is better because when you compose your descriptive statistics, your unit will remain the same, saving you some work to taking a square root.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation is that the poster wants to know quite how to do the correlation calculations ab initio. If you have the original data on weight and hemoglobin, then use the `spearman` command; if you already have the ranks, then use `correlate`, as Spearman correlation is the Pearson correlation applied to the ranks.

On this interpretation, this question is outside the scope of CV, but I answered it any way.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out and used the spearman command. I am just seeing these responses now.